# is there a way to use the UI Umbraco in Angular as a standalone front?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, export, content-management-system, umbraco

I want to create a simple CMS Website. However, I want to have the drag & drop UI of Umbraco and set it in my angular app.
1- Is it possible to export the Umbarco UI to work with it in another application?
2- If it's so, which folder of the Umbarco's open source repository should I copy to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here few different challenges:

- Rendering the views
- SPA features

Umbraco uses Razor to render the views. One of the features of Angular. So in that case, I have to say "no", you can't replicate from Angular what you have in the Umbraco UI. Not without re-inventing the wheel.
However, you can provide an hybrid. Umbraco renders the views, and you handle UI actions with Angular, what is very common.

Other possibility is using Umbraco Headless. But then, forget the Umbraco UI from backoffice, I mean the visual composition of pages, Umbraco will provide data and you will render it with Angular.